# How do I define a derivative of a function and then immediately use that?

Tags: maxima

In other words, how do I concisely express something like "derivative of f(x) with respect to x, evaluated at t"? As in:

```
wxplot2d(
    [
        parametric,
        realpart(zeta(1/2+t*%i) / <derivative of zeta(z) with respect to z evaluated at 1/2 + t*%i>),
        imagpart(zeta(1/2+t*%i) / <derivative of zeta(z) with respect to z evaluated at 1/2 + t*%i>),
        [t,14,80]
    ],
    [same_xy]
)
```

What is the syntax I should use instead of the bits in angle brackets?

Comment: Szczepan, the syntax to represent the part in brackets is `at(diff(zeta(z), z), z = 1/2 + t*%i)` or in general, `at(diff(f(z), z), z = g(t))` where `f` and `g` are some functions. However, it appears that Maxima doesn't know the derivative for the zeta function, so that's not immediately helpful. I'm not sure how to go about calculating that derivative. You will probably get more useful answers on the maxima-discuss mailing list. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: Yes, I kind of figured out in the meantime that my problems are mostly due to Maxima not actually knowing the zeta derivative, but thank you for teling me about `at()`; I will accept if you write this out as the answer.